# What does "dramaturgical" and "mediatized" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

This is the abstract of *Revisiting* *the* *flipped* *classroom*
*in* *a* *design* *context* by Coyne, Lee & Petrova.

> After explaining our experience with a flipped classroom model of learning,
>   we argue that the approach brings to light **the dramaturgical and mediatized
>   aspects of learning experiences that favour a closer connection between
>   recorded content and “live” presentation by the lecturer**. We adopted the
>   flipped classroom approach to learning and teaching in a class of over 100
>   postgraduate level university students, some learning at a distance, and run
>   over two successive years. This article describes the format of the lecture
>   recordings, class activities and assessment method. We also describe the
>   outcome of course evaluation, and present what we learned from the process.

I looked up the meaning of dramaturgical and mediatization and yet I'm still struggling with what is meant starting from **dramaturgical** to the end of the sentence. Your explanation would be much appreciated.

Merriam Webster lists these definitions for *mediatize*:

> transitive verb
>
> 1- to bring (a prince or state) down to the rank of mediate vassal from that of immediate vassal of the Holy Roman Empire :  annex (a state) to another
>       a mediatized prince — Cyril Connolly
>
> 2- to put into a middle or intermediate position :  make instrumental or subordinate
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 1- to act as mediator
>
> 2- to become a mediate vassal of the Holy Roman Empire

none of these definitions could help me figure out what for God's sake these *mediatized* *aspects* could be. To me, dramaturgical is less troublesome as it seems to mean *relating* *to* *the* *techniques* *of* *drama* but then again what does play making have to do with a flipped classroom model of learning? And yes I understand what flipped classroom is. I FEEL LOST

Comment: What definitions did you find that seemed closest to fitting?

Comment: Nothing different than their dictionary definitions.

Comment: Welcome to ELL Sara. Is it the words that are causing a problem or the end of the sentence that they're in that is hard to understand? Would you explain a little bit more why the dictionary didn't help? Do you understand "brings to light"?

Comment: I think they mean the students act like TV presenters and actors? Flipped? Reversing the role of teacher and student? But I have to say, it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I agree with @Lambie. I'd say this bit of a definition from Oxford would be more useful: "By extension: rendered subject to the controlling influence of the mass media." The important thing to realize here is that the root of mediatize is "medium," which has multiple meanings. "Dramaturgy" is a pretty pretentious kind of word for anything having to do with acting and theater.

Answer (score 1):

Elsewhere in that paper:

> In further dramatising the lecture, it brings the “mediatization” [...] of professional life evident in the digital age yet again into sharp relief.

So I guess "mediatized" is being used to mean "made to be like the digital entertainment media".  They are talking about treating teaching as a staged or broadcast drama.

(Unfortunately, my pretentious-academic-jargon filters clogged up before I could read much more of the paper.)

Comment: I'm wondering why they spelled "dramatising" with an _s_ but "mediatization" with a _z_. Seems to me like they're failing at their own pretentiousness. Can't they even decide whether they want to use AmE or BrE spelling?